# bower_components folder not deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

I have a web app project with bower_components folder under wwwroot, however when published to Azure, bower_components folder is not being published, any idea why?

[image]

Comment: How did you publish it to Azure?

Comment: @TonyJu: Right click > publish

Comment: Have you check the KUDU whether the folder is published? I test in my site and work well.

Answer (score 0):

All of Azure Websites workers have bower pre-installed and should be on your path.

All you need to do is add a custom deployment script that would do bower install Here is a sample repo for an [ASP.NET MVC site that uses bower](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower)

Basically make sure bower.json is there and referenced in your csproj

```
<Content Include="bower.json" />
```

Then download your custom deployment script. if you go to `https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net` then click on Tools -> Download custom deployment script or just download it from `D:\home\deployment\tools` then check it in the root of your [repo like](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower/commit/537b3118b50029c75db3bfc11dba2b2212cf1c9e) here basically there will be 2 files deploy.cmd and .deployment

this is the deployment logic, add a step to restore bower in it l[ike here](https://github.com/ahmelsayed-test/MvcWithBower/commit/502ba86e141e5b14c2fbf07933b176ee0cd9c6bf) after the last step there

```
:: 4. Bower Install
if EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json" (
    pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
    call :ExecuteCmd bower install
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
    popd
)
```

Hope it helps.